# Is there anyway to contact instagram API review team?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I am in the middle of the review process for Instagrams new API permissions. We have followed all of their guidelines and fall into one of their valid use cases. Unfortunately we have been denied now 3 times with the only explanation that we don't fall under a valid use case. I would be ok with this response if our software wasn't exactly what they say is a valid use case. So far I am unable to find anyway to contact them or talk about this issue. It would be a lot more helpful if we didn't get a blanket response when getting denied. Anyone else having these issues or have been able to contact their review team?

Comment: This question has to be answered by Instagramm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this helps. I have tried two times but our app was declined. I will write the submission text one more time. I also want to go more into detail as the new FAQ says that Instagram expects a very detailed submision.

Cheers,
Christian

**FAQ**

**My submission was rejected but it was a valid use case. What should I do?**
A common reason for rejecting a submission is that we do not have enough information to make an assessment of your app. This can happen if your submission was too short, if it missed important information, if you did not provide a good screencast, your website is not working, etc. Before you submit for review again, make sure to provide a long and clear explanation of what your app does and how you use every permission. Make sure also to provide a video screencast and to follow all our Platform Policies.

**What should I write in the submission?** 
The submission should be long enough for us to understand exactly what your app does and why you need the permissions you are asking for. If your submission is too short or does not explain all parts of your integration, then we may not be able to understand and approve your app. For example, your submission should explain what does your app or company do, which of the approved use cases your integration falls into, who will be using your app, how do your user authenticate with your app, how you use the API to power your integration, how does your product use the data acquired from Instagram, etc.

**What should I show in the video screencast?**
The video screencast is a very important part of a submission and cannot be omitted. Please make sure that the video clearly shows how your application works, including any Instagram login experience and the usage of every permission you are requesting. Since your app may still be in sandbox mode, you can use data from sandbox users to showcase the integration.

**My company is working with multiple clients, should I submit one app per project?** 
No, we do not approve apps that are created for one-off projects (e.g. a hashtag campaign, an event, a website). You should use a single client_id across all your integrations.

**Can I revoke a submission if I made a mistake?** 
You can't cancel a submission that is in progress. You will need to wait until the submission has been reviewed before you can start a new one.

Answer (score 2):

I also have just been denied in the same way. I gave them 20minutes of video and demonstrated everything my app does. I wrote about each action possible in the context of use case 2 and I clearly stated which calls I was making. Short of supplying the source I am not sure what else to tell them.